# How to loop through JSON and add values to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I am having trouble figuring out how to create an array with two objects, looping through my object and adding some values to those objects in Javascript. Currently I have the following mock response:

```
const mockResponse = 
        {
            "errors": [
              {
                "errorKey": "ERROR_NO_DELIVERY_OPTIONS",
                "errorParameters": [
                  {
                    "errorMessage": "ERROR_DELIVERY_OPTIONS_YOU_SELECTED_NOT_AVAILABLE_NOW",
                    "partNumbers": [
                      19308033,
                      19114798
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "errorMessage": "Ship to Home not available for these orderItemId",
                    "orderItemIds": [
                      10315031,
                      10315032
                    ],
                    "availableShipModeId": 13203
                  },
                  {
                    "errorMessage": "Pickup At Seller not available for these orderItemIds",
                    "orderItemIds": [
                      10222222,
                      10333333
                    ],
                    "availableShipModeId": 13203
                  }
                ],
                "errorMessage": "ERROR_NO_DELIVERY_OPTIONS",
                "errorCode": "ERROR_NO_DELIVERY_OPTIONS"
              }
            ]
          }
```

I would like to have an array with two objects. One for the first error message("Ship to home...") and another for the second error message("Pickup at Seller..."). I would like to then loop through the JSON and add each "orderItemIds" to there respective object. For example, 10315031,10315032 would go to the first object and 10222222, 10333333 to the second.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `mockResponse.errors[0].errorParameters.find(param => param.errorMessage.startsWith("Ship")).orderItemIds`

Comment: JSON is a textual representation of a JS object. You do not have any JSON here

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to loop through your errors and use the errorMessage property as a key

```
const result = mockResponse.errors[0].errorParameters.reduce((prev, item) => {
    const { errorMessage, orderItemIds } = item;
    if (prev[errorMessage]) {
        prev[errorMessage] = [...prev[errorMessage], ...orderItemsIds];
    } else {
        prev[errorMessage] = orderItemIds
    }
    return prev
}, {})
```

Let me know if this does answer your question